# Remove everything after the second occurrence of a string

Tags: sed

Hello I have a file such as:

```
>Inn_can_OIOIEiO
ASNSJNSJSNSS
SNSJJISBSI
SUBSIUBSIBS
>Kio_can_OIOIEiE
ASNSJNSJSNSS
SNSJJISBSI
SUBSIUBSIBS
>Ven_can_OIOIEiB
ASNSJNSJSNSS
SNSJJISBSI
SUBSIUBSIBS
>Lop_can_OIOIEiE
ASNSJNSJSNSS
SNSJJISBSI
SUBSIUBSIBS
>Ven_can_OIOIEiE
ASNSJNSJSNSS
SNSJJISBSI
SUBSIUBSIBS
```

and I would like to remove everything after the second `'>Ven_can'` occurred and get :

```
>Inn_can_OIOIEiO
ASNSJNSJSNSS
SNSJJISBSI
SUBSIUBSIBS
>Kio_can_OIOIEiE
ASNSJNSJSNSS
SNSJJISBSI
SUBSIUBSIBS
>Ven_can_OIOIEiB
ASNSJNSJSNSS
SNSJJISBSI
SUBSIUBSIBS
>Lop_can_OIOIEiE
ASNSJNSJSNSS
SNSJJISBSI
SUBSIUBSIBS
```

Does anyone have an idea using sed for exemple?
Thank you for your help

I now only how to deleted everything after a character with

```
sed '1,@>Ven_can@!d' file1
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/Ven_can/{x;/./Q;x;h}' file
```

Quit without printing the current line if that line is the second occurrence of the string `Ven_can`.